# I'm planning to Install Elementary OS, I just have a few Questions

Tags: system-installation

**Setting Folder Icon?**

I like to set folder icons to my folders, is it possible to do that from the default file manager? or can I use nautilus scripts (or some modified version of it) to change my folder icons in bulk like explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892916/change-folder-icon-of-multiple-folders-movies/900053#900053), or Will I need to get Nautilus?

[image: Screenshot of Folder icons set directory]

**Adding PPA**

I read that PPA's are blocked inside elementary OS, is that still the case? if yes then is their a hack around it?

**Installing GTK Theme**

i'm right now using this [theme](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/11/macbuntu-1610-transformation-pack-for.html), will i be able to use this theme in elementary OS as well? and is their a Tweak tool like Unity Tweak Tool and Gnome Tweak Tool?

**Enable Hibernation**

I need to use Hibernation many times, would i be able to do it in Elementary OS?

**About Updates**

as Ubuntu 17.04 is coming out at the and of this month, how fast Elementary OS will be updated to the New base?

**Other Things**

what other things are different in Elementary OS for a fairly new Linux user who has just used Ubuntu for 6 months?

I'm asking these questions because I don't want to find out missing things after I'm completely soaked in elementary OS?

Comment: Hi Sumeet, you'll want to break these into separate questions (some are already answered in search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Elementary! I can respond to a few of your questions.

PPAs: They are not enabled by default. This is alleviated by running:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common python3-software-properties python-software-properties
```

Themes: Yes themes can be installed. Keep in mind, many elementary apps have client side decorations that don't play well with 3rd party themes. But to use themes first you need to install elementary Tweaks:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Then create a folder called .themes in your home directory and copy the theme folder there. Use elementary Tweaks to enable the theme.

Hibernation: Yes I believe elementary has a form of hibernation (someone correct me if I am wrong on this)

Updates: There is no telling when elementary OS will shift to 17.04. Could be with the next release, Juno. But there is no information on that. elementary doesn't tend to follow regular release schedules but follow a pattern of "it will release when it's ready".

Comment: so that's a **No** for folder icons?

Comment: I can't answer that. Maybe someone else can. Sorry.

Comment: For hibernation you could look at http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/search?q=hibernation+loki

Comment: There are no folder icons in `pantheon-files`, you could still install `nautilus` though.